Failed to install module `PyStruct` using pip
I wanted to install the module PyStray for a project.
I used the generic command ->
pip install Pystruct
Here is the error :
Collecting Pystruct
  Using cached pystruct-0.3.2.tar.gz (5.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Meit Sant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Meit Sant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Meit Sant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Meit Sant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3y5ayshq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\Meit Sant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3y5ayshq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Meit Sant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3y5ayshq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Meit Sant\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3y5ayshq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

As it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy', I installed Numpy using pip install numpy, which completed successfully.
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.26.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl.metadata (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.0/61.0 kB 819.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading numpy-1.26.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (15.8 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.8/15.8 MB 2.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.26.4

However on re-running the command pip install Pystruct. It threw the same error. Even though numpy is installed.

Interesting, I tried installing it and got the same error

PyStray or Pystruct? Pystruct seems to be very old (last commit and release in 2018), buggy and abandoned. I tried a number of Python versions to install with (Python 3.9, 3.8, 3.7), downgraded setuptools and tried tricks with pip but nothing helped. The package seems to be broken. PyStray looks better and newer though I didn't try to install it.

I managed to install it the following way. Use Python 3.8, this is the latest Python that worked for me. Downgrade setuptools to avoid "error in pystruct setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.". Install NumPy. Install from GitHub repo, not from packages at PyPI; you need to have git in your %PATH%. These are the commands:
pip install "setuptools<58" numpy
pip install git+https://github.com/pystruct/pystruct.git

